# How to avoid adding timezone when subtract tow time in php

Tags: php, datetime, time, timezone

My php timezone is `Asia/Dhaka` (UTC+6)

Let I have two time

```
$a = 11:00:00;
$b = 09:00:00;
$sub = $a-$b; //it should return 02:00:00. But it adding the timezone and returns 08:00:00 (02:00:00 + 06:00:00)
```

How to avoid to adding the timezone time from this output?

Comment: Hi Nur, Have you tried setting the default timezone to Asia/Dhaka before running this.

Comment: @Rohit Batra default timezone set 'Asia/Dhaka' in my application

Answer (score 0):

try using the php DateTime

```
$a = '11:00:00';
$b = '09:00:00';

$start_date = new DateTime($a);
$since_start = $start_date->diff(new DateTime($b));
echo "{$since_start->h}:{$since_start->i}:{$since_start->s}";
```

Comment: It would be nicer if you formated the output with [`DateInterval::format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php), like `echo $since_start->format('%H:%I:%S');`.